# How to count how many times the value appears in the matrix

Tags: python

How to count how many times the value appears in the matrix on Python
function that gets a matrix and a number and checks how many times the number is inside the matrix and returns the value

```
def how_many(mat,number):
    counter = 0
    counter =  list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda z:x  += 1 if z == mat , x)), mat))

    return counter
```

example: matrix {**1**,2,3,**1**} and number = **1**

print: 2

Comment: `{1,2,3,1}` is not possible in python, this is a set and would keep only one instance of 1

Answer (score 2):

Use `count` method of `list` (if your matrix is a list)

```
def how_many(mat, number):
    return mat.count(number)

print(how_many([1, 2, 3, 1], 1))

# Output:
2
```

Comment: print(how_many(matrix(2),1))
return 0....

Comment: What is the type of your matrix? try `print(type(mat))`. `mat` is the variable that contains your matrix.

Comment: there more choice without print(type(mat)). mat??